# Coded UI conditional check on a method is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create an automated test in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 in coded UI that purchases a membership and then clicks the continue button after the checkout page is displayed. One of my method recorded is to click the continue button after the checkout page. However, that button is not always displayed and so I need to have a conditional check if that button is visible.

```
openBrowser();
goToTestPage();
purchaseMembership()
clickCheckout();
```

I tried creating a conditional check after the above method like this:

```
if (this.UIMap.clickContinueButton !=null) 
{
    clickContinueButton();
}
```

I tried creating an assertation as well but that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out :)

since I was unable to call clickContinueButton, I opened up the the .uitest file (XML version), I located the method from the UI Actions in the left hand section. Then I expanded the clickContinueButton method and found the actual 'click' step. Right click on the click step and choose properties, in the Common properties dialog, change Continue On Error to 'True' and save it.

Now the designer.cs should be updated for the actual method. Open the designer.cs class and locate the clickContinueButton, once you find it copy the region variable e.g:

```
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlInputButton uIIacknowledgeContinueButton = this.UILoopWindowsIntWindow.UILoopDocument1.UIIacknowledgeContinueButton;
        #endregion
```

next step is to open up the UIMap.cs file and create a new boolean method that returns true if the above variable is not null e.g:

```
 public boolean isButtonDisplayed {

        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlInputButton uIIacknowledgeContinueButton = this.UILoopWindowsIntWindow.UILoopDocument1.UIIacknowledgeContinueButton;
        #endregion

 if (uIIacknowledgeContinueButton != null) {

 return true;
 } else {

 return false;
 }
```

Now the final step is to open the codedUItest.cs locate where the clickContinue() method is and add the following conditional statement:

```
 if (isButtonDisplayed() != false) {
 clickContinueButton();
 }
```

hope this helps!
let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several properties of the control that may provide what you need, the exact method or combination of methods depends on the way the web site, or the application, being tested has been written.

Try the `Exists` or `Enabled` properties of the control accessed by the `this.UIMap.clickContinueButton()` method. You can find the control via the UI Map editor, or by right-clicking on the method call and selecting **Go To Definition**.

Sometimes the control exists but is not visible; for example, entries in a drop-down list. These invisible entries can be detected because their `Left` and/or `Top` properties are negative. The `BoundingRectangle`, `Height` and `Width` properties might also be used.

Assuming the control 'clicked' in the method is `uIIacknowledgeContinueButton` then another approach is to use code such as:

```
UITestControlCollection controls
    = uIIacknowledgeContinueButton.FindMatchingControls();
if ( controls.Count == 0 ) {
    // The button is not present.
} else if ( controls.Count == 1) {
    // The button is present.
} else {
    // More than one button has been found.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian, however when I try the following approaches (e.g. this.UIMap.clickContinueButton.Exists or Enabled I get the following error:

Cannot Implicitly convert type 'void' to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControlCollection.


I get the above error when I try all the approaches you stated above. Is it possible to have the recorded method return a value back?

Comment: My original answer mistakenly used the method name rather than the UI control's name, hence the error messages.